# Django 2.0: Send data from a view to a template that is included in another template (2 different Apps)

Tags: python, django, django-templates, view

I'm working on a Django Project that has two apps, **home** and **contact**.

I would like to send the context dictionary from the contact view to the contact_form.html template, which is included in the home.html template.

I can't figure out the way to pass the values to the contact_form.html template because there's not a url for the contact\views.py.

**home\urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

**home\views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, "home/home.html", {})
```

**templates\home\home.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Home template</h1>
    {% include 'contact/contact_form.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

**contact\views.py:**

```
def contact_view(request):
    context = {'hello_contact': 'hello from contact view'}
    return render(request, 'contact/contact_form.html', context)
```

**templates\contact\contact_form.html:**

```
<h2>Contact Template</h2>
<p>{{ hello_contact }}</p>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It doesn't work that way at all. The entire template, including the included template, is rendered by the `home` view. `contact_view` has nothing to do with anything here and is not called.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, thanks for your answer. Even if it doesn't work this way, how would you approach this. I've tried to import one view into the other view, but I can't get it working

Comment: Why can't you do it all in the `home` view?

Comment: @DanielRoseman. 1st. Because I want to learn.  2nd. Because as far as I know, an App should have a very clear function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. There's only one view that gets called by your incoming request, and so only one view that renders your template, including included templates. So that view has to set the all context variables. In your case, `home`.

Comment: @dikrgroten, thanks for your answer. How would handle to import data from one app to another. I tried to import the contact view into the home view but it didn't work. Thanks!